# append extra data to request.POST in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, http-post

I am working on a PDF show feature in Django,
the user enters data in HTML form and can click on the `Preview` button to see the preview in PDF format.

These are the lines in my views.py which return pdf as the response:

```
pdf = render_to_pdf('new_pdf.html', params)
return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

here `render_to_pdf()` takes HTML template and normal Python dictionary to embed data on HTML page and convert it to PDF.

I am currently passing form POST data as params i.e.
`params = {'data':request.POST}`

request.POST looks like this

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['some_random_string_here'], 'client_id': ['26'], 'note_no': ['5']}>
```

and some more fields...

now I can simply use `{{data.client_id}}` in my HTML to get the data.

Everything's working fine till now

but I need to supply some extra data to my params to show on the PDF.

I was wondering if there's a way I can append my extra variables in `request.POST` like

```
request.POST['credit_type'] = [credit_type]
```

but this is not a regular python dictionary and gives
`This QueryDict instance is immutable`.

Is there any work-around for this??

Or do I have to use the regular approach of appending key-value pairs to my `params` and then use them?

Comment: I would rather tend to use the "regular" approach and fill a context and even validate POST data before filling it into the context. Then you have a clean context.

Comment: I am currently using this data to simply show in pdf (no database role) that's why I am relying on HTML and javascript validations for this particular part...
and yes, I am validating POST data in the backend before saving in the database...
anyways thanks for the suggestion :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    updated_request = request.POST.copy()
    updated_request.update({'credit_type': [credit_type]})
```

Comment: this updates the variables in the request.POST and also keeps the data type the same...
thanks for the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try to unpack the `request.POST` dictionary and add your own key-value pairs. This way you keep the original dictionary intact.

```
new_dict = {**request.POST, 'custom_key': custom_val}
```

Comment: Note that this produces `dict`, _not_ a Django `QueryDict`, which is what `request.POST` is. The two have significantly different behavior.